# EventHandlerList missing in PCL project but available on platform library projects (Android/iOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, target, portable-class-library

I have small problem - I'm trying to implement class that needs to contain a lot of events. Due to memory concerns I planned to implement EventHandlerList which is available for me in my Android Library project target also in my iOS Library project target but is not available for me inside PCL Project. Tried to change PCL Target project to most commonly used but none of them contained what i needed.

Type missing for my case :

```
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList
```

Is there any possibility to write such class once or I'm forced to write it two times because of missing PCL Target.

Answer (score 2):

You will need Inversion Of Control (IoC) to use platform specific features or non-portable methods

Please take a look at this [IoC example](http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/)

Another option if you want to avoid IoC is to use [Shared Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) in Xamarin

Comment: I surely understand that you can resolving such dependency using inversion of control, but if a class is available on Android Library and iOS Library in the same time wouldn't be nice to have it in any pcl target? Right now i have to resolve 100% the same code on both sides.

Comment: Right now i used Shared Asset class to work with it. Not even a single directive is needed for that

Comment: It maybe available in both platforms but you are actually want to use it in a PCL which is totally different. `System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList` is not available to be used in a PCL apparently

Comment: What you can do if you want to used it without a IoC is to create a Shared Project with Xamarin and use it from there.

Comment: @PatrykRomańczuk i have added a reference link to Shared Project in the answer

Comment: Shared project is exactly what i used. It's sad that this class is not available on any pcl target. It could be